# Get eventemitter messages from method of object Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

I want to get all progress and updates of loop from this object method. I have used `eventEmitter` to emit a message and then catch that signal with `.on` like this:

```
let response= site_ob.getAllProducts();
    response.on(('gotit'),(data)=>{
        console.log("data");
    });
```

But it shows response.on is not a function.

Below is a method of a class:

```
async getAllProducts(){
        const eventEmitter=new EventEmitter();
        let ended=false,products_array = [],count=0,promises_array = [];
        let total_products_num=this.getTotalProductNumbers();

        for(let i=0;i<=150;i+=50) {

              let products_data=  await this.getProducts(i, 50);
            products_array.push(products_data);
            eventEmitter.emit('gotit', products_data);
        }

        return products_array;
    }
```

Or can I use pipe or stream to do this?

Comment: Edited post and added some more info

Comment: You need to have your class extend eventemitter and then call this.emit() in getAllProducts. As it stand your call the on function on an array as your return your products_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your class extend eventemitter and then call this.emit() in getAllProducts. As it stand your call the on function on an array as your return your products_array

```
class MyProductClass extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async getAllProducts(){
        let ended=false,products_array = [],count=0,promises_array = [];
        let total_products_num=this.getTotalProductNumbers();

        for(let i=0;i<=150;i+=50) {
            let products_data =  await this.getProducts(i, 50);
            products_array.push(products_data);
        }
        
        this.emit('gotit', products_data);
    }

}
```

Then call it like this

```
let response;
site_ob.on( 'gotit', ( data ) => {
    response = data;
    console.log(response);
}

site_ob.getAllProducts();
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks